# Laravel excel get total number of rows before import

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

Straight forward question. How does one get the total number of rows in a spreadsheet with laravel-excel?

I now have a working counter of how many rows have been processed (in the `CompanyImport` file), but I need the total number of rows before I start adding the rows to the database.

The sheet I'm importing is almost 1M rows, so I am trying to create a progress bar.

My import:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    # Counter
    ++$this->currentRow;

    # Dont create or validate on empty rows
    # Bad workaround
    # TODO: better solution
    if (!array_filter($row)) {
        return null;
    }

    # Create company
    $company = new Company;
    $company->crn = $row['crn'];
    $company->name = $row['name'];
    $company->email = $row['email'];
    $company->phone = $row['phone'];
    $company->website = (!empty($row['website'])) ? Helper::addScheme($row['website']) : '';
    $company->save();

    # Everything empty.. delete address
    if (!empty($row['country']) || !empty($row['state']) || !empty($row['postal']) || !empty($row['address']) || !empty($row['zip'])) {

        # Create address
        $address = new CompanyAddress;
        $address->company_id = $company->id;
        $address->country = $row['country'];
        $address->state = $row['state'];
        $address->postal = $row['postal'];
        $address->address = $row['address'];
        $address->zip = $row['zip'];
        $address->save();

        # Attach
        $company->addresses()->save($address);

    }

    # Update session counter
    Session::put('importCurrentRow', $this->currentRow);

    return $company;

}
```

My controller:

```
public function postImport(Import $request)
{
    # Import
    $import = new CompaniesImport;

    # Todo
    # Total number of rows in the sheet to session
    Session::put('importTotalRows');

    #
    Excel::import($import, $request->file('file')->getPathname());

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Would this work for you? https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/progress-bar.html

Comment: @ascsoftw No, sorry. That is for when you're using the console command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below code to calculate number of rows

```
Excel::import($import, 'users.xlsx');

dd('Row count: ' . $import->getRowCount());
```

You can check the [Docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/architecture/objects.html#getters)

**Update**

The above method was for calculating the rows which have been imported so far.
In order to get number of rows which are in the sheet, you need to use `getHighestRow`

```
    Excel::load($file, function($reader) {
        $lastrow = $reader->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
        dd($lastrow);
    });
```

This has been referenced [here](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/2317#issuecomment-518117298) by author of the Plugin.

Comment: But isn't that for how you get the current row that you're processing? 
Or am i wrong?

Comment: Excel::load() is removed and replaced by Excel::import($yourImport) See https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/upgrade.html#upgrading-to-3-from-2-1

Answer (score 12):

In Laravel Excel 3.1 you can get the total rows by implementing `WithEvents` and listening to `beforeImport` event.

```php
<?php
namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeImport;

class UserImport extends ToModel, WithEvents {
    [...]

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            BeforeImport::class => function (BeforeImport $event) {
                $totalRows = $event->getReader()->getTotalRows();

                if (!empty($totalRows)) {
                    echo $totalRows['Worksheet'];
                }
            }
        ];
    }

    [...]
}
```

The key **Worksheet** can be different depending on your Excel file sheet name(s). A user might name it **Sheet1** while another user may name it **Worksheet**.
So if you're sure your users will upload a file that has only one sheet you could avoid problems by getting the total row count from the array's first element like this:

```php
$totalRowCount = reset($totalRows);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: This is a better solution

Comment: How do you access the `$totalRows` from a controller calling the Import? I mean `Excel::import(new UsersImport($this->record), $data['excel_file'],'excel')`?

Comment: Or how to tell when an Import has finished from the controller?

Comment: @Pathros You can use a setter and getter for the `$totalRows` in the `UserImport` class and access that in your controller.

Comment: Hello, sorry with this, but I'm working with import sheets in laravel, and if I copy, paste your code, send me this: Undefined array key "Worksheet". I replace the name with my sheet names, but don't work, can you help me please?

Answer (score 4):

1.- Make file for import

```
php artisan make:import ImportableImport
```

2.- Your File Import

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;

class ImportablesImport implements ToCollection
{

    use Importable;

    /**
    * @param Collection $collection
    */
    public function collection(Collection $collection)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

3.- Your controller

```
$array = (new ImportablesImport)->toArray($file);
dd(count($array[0]));
```

This doc: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/importables.html

Comment: One Milliion records to array ? are you sure it works ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get number of rows before import

```
$fileExtension     = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$temporaryFileFactory=new \Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\TemporaryFileFactory(
    config('excel.temporary_files.local_path', 
            config('excel.exports.temp_path', 
            storage_path('framework/laravel-excel'))
    ),
    config('excel.temporary_files.remote_disk')
);


$temporaryFile = $temporaryFileFactory->make($fileExtension);
$currentFile = $temporaryFile->copyFrom($file,null);            
$reader = \Maatwebsite\Excel\Factories\ReaderFactory::make(null,$currentFile);
$info = $reader->listWorksheetInfo($currentFile->getLocalPath());
$totalRows = 0;
foreach ($info as $sheet) {
    $totalRows+= $sheet['totalRows'];
}
$currentFile->delete();
```

The code taken from Laravel Excel libary

Answer (score 0):

#### Check Below Example:

```
$sheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:A' . $sheet->getHighestRow())->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

by using **getHighestRow()** method you can fetch the total number of rows. In the above code sample I've applied font as BOLD to the second cell of first column till the maximum row count of that same first column.

**Detailed Code Snippet of another example:**

```
$excel->sheet('Employee Details', function ($sheet) use ($AllData) {
                $sheet->fromArray($AllData);
                $sheet->setAutoSize(true);
                $sheet->getStyle('A2:A' . $sheet->getHighestRow())->applyFromArray(array('alignment' => array('horizontal' => \PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT)));
                
            });
```