# How to count row in excel file import in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to count row in excel file which file i import to db .

```php
    public function import(Request $req)
        {
            $this->validate($req,[
                'select_file' => 'required|mimes: xls,xlsx'
            ],[
                'select_file.required' => 'Vui lòng chọn file',
                'select_file.mimes'    => 'Yêu cầu file .xls hoặc .xlsx'
            ]);
            $data = Excel::import(new ExcelImport, request()->file('select_file'));
            $row = count($data);
        }
```

It appears an error like this:

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: `dd($data)` and see result before count it

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57942626/1309690

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel excel get total number of rows before import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942366/laravel-excel-get-total-number-of-rows-before-import)

Answer (score -3):

try using `getRowCount` [getter](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/architecture/objects.html#getters)

```
$excel = new ExcelImport;
$data = Excel::import($excel, request()->file('select_file'));
$row = $excel->getRowCount();
```

Comment: it error : Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::getRowCount()